# Discord search specific string in channel and re-post the whole message

Tags: discord, discord.js

What is Discord code for bot search specific word in channel, and then return the whole messages of that string?

For example ppl try some tips about cooking : ?cook Apple Pie
Then bot will re-post 2 or 3 tips about Apple Pie recipes, based on the messages found with Apple Pie as a keyword from the channel messages

Comment: Theres a search functionality already built into the discord client.

Answer (score 0):

You first of all need to create a command handler then fill in if commands for each message. Here is an example below. I assume you know how to properly login and/or set up your bot with "const Discord = require("discord.js"); and const client = new Discord.Client();" and "client.login("token")". If you do you can try the code below.

```js
//Assign Prefix
const prefix = "?";

client.on("message", async message => {
//Stop the Bot from Replying to its own messages:
  if(message.author.bot) return;
//Check for the Prefix:
  if(message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;

//Command Arguments
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

//The Command itself
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//Simple Example Where the Bots Detects ?hello and responds with World
  if(command === "Hello"){
    messsage.reply("World");
  }

//For Arguments like your Apple Pie Example, This is what you will have to do:
  if(command === "cook"){
    const commandArgument = args.join(" ");
    switch(commandArgument){
        default:
          message.reply("Please Send An Argument After the Command");
          break;
        case "Apple Pie":
          message.channel.send("APPLE PIE RECIPE TIPS:")
          break;
        case "Blueberry Pie":
          message.channel.send("Blueberry Pie Recipe Tips:")
    }
  }
});
```

You should also read the API for discord.js at: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

And the Guide: https://discordjs.guide/

If you haven't downloaded discord.js on your computer you should do so from https://discord.js.org/ but I assume you have.

If you are still unsure you should watch some youtube videos explaining discord.js and you should have basic JavaScript Knowledge.

-Joshua

Comment: Hi Joshua,<br/>
What I want is the apple pie recipe is from some other people msg that has been posted in the channel.<br/>
<br/>
For example<br/>
A : post apple pie recipe is 1234<br/>
B : post apple pie recipe is 345<br/>
<br/>
When C send ?cook apple pie.<br/>
Bot will search the channel and get those A and B msg as the result and return as a msg to C in the channel.

Comment: in simple word, bot search for message in channel based on keyword, and post the whole message.

thanks